# Expressing a number in radix-$n$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I'm working through a section in the CLRS book "Introduction to Algorithms" regarding hashing.

The following example is given in regards to interpreting keys as natural numbers:

"Thus, we might interpret the identifier "pt" as the pair of decimal integers $(112,116)$, since $p=112$ and $t=116$ in the ASCII character set; then, expressed as a radix-$128$ integer, "pt" becomes $(112 \cdot 128) + 116= 14452$."

This confuses me as it seems that expressing $(112,116)$ as a radix-$128$ integer would simply be $(112,116)_{128}$ and then converting to a radix-$10$ integer would yield $14452_{10}$. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: You (correctly) rehashed what the book said. Where is the confusing part?

Comment: The book mentions that expressing $(112,116)$ as a radix-$128$ integer gives us $14452$, but this is expressing $(112,116)$ as a radix-$10$ integer not a radix-$128$.

Comment: $112$ and $116$ are *digits* in base $128\,$, so $(112,116)_{128}= 112 \cdot 128 + 116=14452_{10}\,$. Just like in base $10$ a number $(4,2)_{10}=4 \cdot 10 + 2 = 42_{10}\,$.